# WIX Create folder from values present in file during installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am a Wix novice, first of all. I am trying to create an installer using Wix. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I have Wix toolkit installed.

In my installer I have a version.ini file which contains the version information. During each build, the version.ini file will be updated. I need to create a folder using the version specified in version.ini and copy some files to that folder created during installation. I prefer the version.ini should not be deployed during installation.

I went through some threads here. What I got is since the version.ini file is present during build time, we need to use it rather than creating custom actions. But I don't know how.

Can someone help? I really appreciate if you could provide sample code.

Thanks,
ssn

Comment: It seems like you want to create WiX files from the information in version.ini. Please add relevant parts to your question. Also, are you using Visual Studio (or MSBuild) with a .wixproj, or are you running WiX tools directly?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and I have Wix toolkit installed. My requirement is I have 3 files to copy to a folder. But the folder name is included in version.ini. I want to create a folder with name specified in version.ini and copy the 3 files to that folder.

Comment: Just to be clear, your version.ini could change with each build of the installer so you want to automate copying out the destination folder name into the WiX files before building the project, right? If so, please edit your question to show what your version.ini and Wix files look like. In other words, to it once by hand before automating it so you can eliminate questions about that first.